# ffmpeg channels don't work (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, ffmpeg, jsfiddle

I have a lot of channels with " ffmpeg " (4 channels) that start automatically, I create a code for show the first channel and after 5 seconds show the second .. Etc All things as right but I have a small problem the seconds channel doesn't start automatically, I need to make stop to the first channel

Code for 4 channel work 100% but without function for show first channel and after 5 seconds show the second ... Etc

```html
<?php

ffmpeg -i http://clay24.webhop.net:8000/live/mario/mario/13.ts -i http://clay24.webhop.net:8000/live/mario/mario/12.ts -i http://clay24.webhop.net:8000/live/mario/mario/10.ts -map 0 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -strict -2 -preset fast -crf 25 -vcodec libx264 -f flv rtmp://178.33.231.108:1989/mylive/1 -map 1 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -strict -2 -preset fast -crf 25 -vcodec libx264 -f flv rtmp://178.33.231.108:1989/mylive/21 -map 2 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -strict -2 -preset fast -crf 25 -vcodec libx264 -f flv rtmp://178.33.231.108:1989/mylive/24

?>
```

the second code with functions

```js
<?php
echo'
    <script>

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {

var urls = iframes = [ "'; ffmpeg -i http://mygameravatar.zapto.org:43666/live/test1/test2/81.ts -c:a aac -b:a 64k -preset fast -crf 25 -vcodec libx264 -f flv rtmp://178.33.231.108:1989/mylive/2 
 echo '];

var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("div");

var n = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  
  iframes[++n].src = urls[n - 1];
  iframes[n].style.display = "block";
  console.log(n);
  if (n === iframes.length -1) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log("all iframes loaded")
  }
  
}, 5000)

})
 </script>
 
 <style>
 .channel {
  display:none;
  }
 </style>
 
 
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
 ';

 ffmpeg -i http://mygameravatar.zapto.org:43666/live/test1/test2/297.ts -c:a aac -b:a 64k -preset fast -crf 25 -vcodec libx264 -f flv rtmp://178.33.231.108:1989/mylive/1 
 
 
 echo '</div>
 
 <div class="channel">

 </div>


  </body>

</html>';
?>
```

Comment: why that console command marked as php?

Comment: @llamerr I don't understand

Comment: me neither. you put some console command for `ffmpeg` between php tags. how is that suppose to work?

Comment: In the first code I make map function, that work without any problem but in the second I have a problem I can't see all channels in the same times. I need to stop first channel to see the second .. Etc

Comment: if you want to receive answer to this, try to add jsfiddle that other people can check to see the problem, because I can't get any idea of what you want to achieve looking at that mess of js/php/html/bash code

Comment: Is the issue with your code or with `ffmpeg`? Does the `ffmpeg` command work as expected if you run it manually in command line interface? You need to include the complete output/log from your `ffmpeg` command; otherwise we can only make guesses, not answers.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard the first code is work without any problem. I have problem with the second code

Comment: Do you not get any error messages from `ffmpeg` or your code?

Comment: If I make <?php I have a error said :  `syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING)` If I deleted I don't see any Error